Can one make a minimizable palette?
I would like to minimize my palettes sometimes.
This was the closest that I could find, but it's not quite the same. Also, the WindowFloating options is deprecated as of 14.0 .

Palette is created as a tool window (read more about this in my other answer). Such windows do not appear in the OS taskbar, and they are usually not minimizable.
You can make it minimizable by changing the WindowFrame and explicitly specifying WindowFrameElements:
CreatePalette[{"My very interesting palette, capable of being minimized"},
 WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox", "MinimizeBox"},
 WindowFrame -> "ModelessDialog"
 ]


However, when you minimize, it will go to the bottom of the screen. You also have to change WindowClickSelect to make it be present in the taskbar.
CreatePalette[{"My very interesting palette, capable of being minimized"},
 WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox", "MinimizeBox"},
 WindowFrame -> "ModelessDialog",
 WindowClickSelect -> True
 ]


You cannot get the behaviors of a palette without WindowClickSelect being set to False.  i.e. PasteButton and friends will no longer work as one would expect.
